# Bash shell `if` command returns something `then` do something

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I am trying to do an if/then statement, where if there is non-empty output from a `ls | grep something` command then I want to execute some statements. I am do not know the syntax I should be using. I have tried several variations of this:

```
if [[ `ls | grep log ` ]]; then echo "there are files of type log";
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004 ("How can I check whether a directory is empty or not? How do I check for any *.mpg files, or count how many there are?") is somewhat relevant to the immediate issue at hand.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, that's close, but you need to finish the `if` with `fi`.

Also, `if` just runs a command and executes the conditional code if the command succeeds (exits with status code 0), which `grep` does only if it finds at least one match. So you don't need to check the output:

```
if ls | grep -q log; then echo "there are files of type log"; fi
```

If you're on a system with an older or non-GNU version of `grep` that doesn't support the `-q` ("quiet") option, you can achieve the same result by redirecting its output to `/dev/null`:

```
if ls | grep log >/dev/null; then echo "there are files of type log"; fi
```

In this particular case, you can do without `grep` entirely, since `ls` returns nonzero if it doesn't find a specified filename, as in D.Shawley's answer:

```
if ls *log* >&/dev/null; then echo "there are files of type log"; fi
```

But in Zsh, or Bash with the `failglob` option set, such a command will error out if the wildcard doesn't match anything, without ever actually running `ls`. You can take advantage of that behavior to check without needing `ls` at all:

```
# Zsh, or Bash with failglob set
if (echo *log*) >&/dev/null; then
  echo "there are files of type log"
fi
```

Or you could set `nullglob` instead:

```
# with 'nullglob' set, in either Bash or Zsh
for f in *log*; do
  echo "There are files of type log"
  break
done
```

In Ksh, or Bash without either option set, it's a little more work:

```
# Ksh or Bash without failglob or nullglob
for f in *log*; do 
  # even if there are no matching files, the body of this loop will run once
  # with $f set to the literal string "*log*", so make sure there's really
  # a file there:
  if [ -e "$f" ]; then 
    echo "there are files of type log"
    break
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Or without `if; then; fi`:

```
ls | grep -q log && echo 'there are files of type log'
```

Or even:

```
ls *log* &>/dev/null && echo 'there are files of type log'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `if` built-in executes a shell command and selects the block based on the return value of the command.  `ls` returns a distinct status code if it does not find the requested files so there is no need for the `grep` part.  The `[[` *utility* is actually a built-in command from bash, IIRC, that performs arithmetic operations.  I could be wrong on that part since I rarely stray far from Bourne shell syntax.

Anyway, if you put all of this together, then you end up with the following command:

```
if ls *log* > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "there are files of type log"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I was rather set on using grep. I intend to filter through several regular expression rules, and maybe filter output from other commands besides ls. I was using ls as an example so that solving my format will allow me to write many many more similar commands. Cheers ,~)

Comment: @BillyMoon - you might want to consider using `find` instead of grepping the output of `ls`.  If you do use `ls`, then use the full path so that you do not get surprised by someone's alias of `ls`.

Comment: @D.Shawley you can also just use `command ls`, which bypasses both aliases and functions without depending on a specific path to the command.